# Using wordpress for authentication in jQuery Mobile, PhoneGap app

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, security, jquery-mobile

I have built an app using jQuery mobile and PhoneGap.
The app fetches content from a Wordpress website using ajax and a Wordpress json plugin.

Now i wish to extend the functionality of the app to give users the posibility to update content.

For this they would have to login in wordpress.

I intend it to work somethin like this:

1. Username & password sent from client to server with ajax
2. Return token back to client from server
3. Store token in client (local storage)
4. Send that token with each requests to server and validate it
   serverside.

**Edit:**
So far I got this to create the token and return it:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_priv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );


function ajax_login(){

    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Invalid username or password.')));
    } else {

        $expiration = $expire = time() + (14 * 24 * 60 * 60);

        $pass_frag = substr($user->user_pass, 8, 4);

        $key = wp_hash($user->user_login . $pass_frag . '|' . $expiration, $scheme);
        $hash = hash_hmac('md5', $user->user_login . '|' . $expiration, $key);

        $token = $user->user_login . '|' . $expiration . '|' . $hash;


        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'token'=>$token, 'message'=>__('Login successful...')));

    }

    die();
}
```

And this to verify the token:

```
function token_auth($token){

    list($username, $expiration, $hmac) = $token;

    $expired = $expiration;

    // Allow a grace period for POST and AJAX requests
    if ( defined('DOING_AJAX') || 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] )
        $expired += HOUR_IN_SECONDS;

    // Quick check to see if an honest cookie has expired
    if ( $expired < time() ) {
        return false;
    }

    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);
    if ( ! $user ) {
        return false;
    }

    $pass_frag = substr($user->user_pass, 8, 4);

    $key = wp_hash($username . $pass_frag . '|' . $expiration, $scheme);
    $hash = hash_hmac('md5', $username . '|' . $expiration, $key);

    if ( $hmac != $hash ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( $expiration < time() ) // AJAX/POST grace period set above
        $GLOBALS['login_grace_period'] = 1;

    return true;

    wp_set_current_user( $user->ID );


}
```

And heres the js:

```
$('form#login').submit( function(e){
                    $('form#login p.status').show().text('Sending user info, please wait...');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: 'http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
                        username: $('form#login #username').val(),
                        password: $('form#login #password').val(),
                        data: { 
                            'action': 'ajaxlogin',
                            'username': $('form#login #username').val(), 
                            'password': $('form#login #password').val() },
                        success: function(data){
                            $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
                            if (data.loggedin == true){
                                $.mobile.changePage( "/blog.html", { changeHash: false });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

Still work in progress.

Is there some way to encrypt passwords incase someone is not using https?

Comment: The question has turned more into a security one since i figured out most of the other stuff...

Comment: Did you get this working?  I am looking into doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom plugin that defines a couple of new URLs. One URL / function would be to login and return a valid token (if a valid login). The other URL / function would be to validate that the token is still valid.

With having it as your own custom plugin, you also have the option of creating a separate role / capabilities that you could use for this purpose...if the granularity is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID );` if login is successful to set the authentication cookies which will be used by all subsequent requests.